# In classical state discrimination, why does the trace distance quantify the probability of success?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, information-theory, state-discrimination

Consider the following task: we are given a probability distribution $p_y:x\mapsto p_y(x)$ with $y\in\{0,1\}$ (*e.g.* we are given some black box that we can use to draw samples from either $p_0$ or $p_1$), and we want to recover the value of $y$.
Assume $x\in X$ for some finite register $X$.
We can assume we know what the possible distributions $p_y$ are, and we also know the probability $\lambda_y$ with which each $y$ can occur: $\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y)=\lambda_y$.

Now, suppose we got our box, used it, and obtained the result $x$. Knowing $\lambda,p_0,p_1$, what's our best guess for $y$? Well, we know that $\mathrm{Pr}(X=x|Y=y)=p_y(x)$, and thus from Bayes that
$$\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{\lambda_y p_y(x)}{p(x)}, \quad \text{where}\quad p(x)\equiv \sum_y \lambda_y p_y(x).$$
It then stands to reason that, knowing $x$, our best guess for $y$ is the one that maximises this probability:
$$y_{\rm opt}(x)=\mathrm{argmax}_y\mathrm{Pr}(Y=y|X=x)=\mathrm{argmax}_y \lambda_y p_y(x).$$
Using such guess, the probability of guessing right (using the knowledge of $x$) would then be
$$p_{\rm correct}(x) = \max_y \mathrm{Pr}(Y=y|X=x) = \frac{\max_y \lambda_y p_y(x)}{p(x)}.$$

We would now like to know what is the probability of correctly identifying $y$ *without* having sampled from $p_y$. Naively, I would compute this as the average of $p_{\rm correct}(x)$ weighted over the probabilities $p(x)$, which would give
$$p_{\rm correct} = \sum_x p(x)p_{\rm correct}(x) = \sum_x \max_y \lambda_y p_y(x).\tag A$$
However, *e.g.* in [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/) (around Eq. (3.2), pag 126, though I'm using a slightly different notation here), the author mentions that the probability of correctly identifying $y$ oughts to be calculated by considering the probability that the guess is right minus the probability that it is not, and that this would result in the quantity
$$\sum_{x\in X}\left\lvert \lambda_0 p_0(x)- \lambda_1 p_1(x)\right\rvert
= \|\lambda_0 p_0 - \lambda_1 p_1\|_1,\tag B$$
from which we would recover the probability of being correct as $p_{\rm correct}=\frac12(1+\|\lambda_0 p_0-\lambda_1 p_1\|_1)$.

Assuming the reasoning that led me to (A) is correct, why is my expression for $p_{\rm correct}$ compatible with the one resulting from (B)?

Answer (score 2):

Upon some additional reflection, I found a way to see that the expressions are equivalent. I'm not sure whether this is the way that was intended in the text though, there might be better/more direct ways to get to the expression with the trace norm.

The basic idea is to observe that for any $a,b\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$(a+b)+|a-b| = 2\max(a,b).$$
Using this result, we can write
$$2\max_y \lambda_y p_y(x) = \sum_y \lambda_y p_y(x) + \lvert\lambda_0 p_0(x)-\lambda_1 p_1(x)\rvert.$$
Summing over $x$ we thus get
$$2p_{\rm correct} = 2\sum_x \max_y \lambda_y p_y(x)
= \underbrace{\sum_x \sum_y \lambda_y p_y(x)}_{=1} + \sum_x \lvert\lambda_0 p_0(x)-\lambda_1 p_1(x)\rvert,$$
and therefore
$$p_{\rm correct} = \frac12\left(1 + \|\lambda_0 p_0 - \lambda_1 p_1\|_1\right).$$