# Is the quantum state discrimination success probability always $\lambda_0\langle\mu(0),\rho_0\rangle+\lambda_1\langle\mu(1),\rho_1\rangle$?

Tags: information-theory, state-discrimination

Consider the standard quantum state discrimination setup: Alice sends Bob either $\rho_0$ or $\rho_1$. She picks $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ with probabilities $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$, respectively. Bob performs some two-outcome measurement $\mu$ on the state he receives and has to decide whether Alice sent $\rho_0$ or $\rho_1$.
We assume Bob knows the possible states $\rho_0,\rho_1$, as well as the probabilities $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$.

Denote with $p_i(b)\equiv p_i^\mu(b)\equiv \langle \mu(b),\rho_i\rangle\equiv \mathrm{Tr}(\mu(b)\rho_i)$ the probability of Bob observing the outcome $b\in\{0,1\}$ when the state he received is $\rho_i$.
If Bob measures the outcome $b$, his best guess is that he received the $\rho_i$ with $i$ maximising $\lambda_i p_i(b)$.
This follows from simple Bayesian considerations, fully analogous to the classical state discrimination scenario discussed [in this other question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15970/55).

Consequently, when Bob finds the outcome $b$, the probability of his guess being correct is
$$p_{\rm correct}(b) = \frac{\max_i \lambda_i p_i(b)}{p(b)} = \frac{\max_i \lambda_i p_i(b)}{\sum_i \lambda_i p_i(b)}.$$
The overall success probability, estimated before knowing the measurement outcome, is therefore
$$p_{\rm correct} = \sum_b p(b) p_{\rm correct}(b) = \sum_b \max_i \lambda_i p_i(b).\tag X$$

This is all nice and well. However, the success probability for this type of scenario is usually given (*e.g.* in [Watrous' TQI](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/), section *3.1*) as the expression:
$$p_{\rm correct}'=\sum_{i\in\{0,1\}} \lambda_i p_i(i).\tag Y$$
This expression is intuitively clear: if Bob receives $\rho_i$, which happens with probability $\lambda_i$, then he correctly guesses that the state was $i$ with probability $p_i(i)$.

Nonetheless, I wonder: are (X) and (Y) always equivalent?
I suppose that if we assume that the best guess changes with the observed outcome (*e.g.* if Bob finds $b=0$ then his best guess is $i=0$, and if he finds $b=1$ his best guess is $i=1$), then (X) and (Y) are equivalent up to a relabeling of the POVM.
But can we always assume this? Isn't it possible that there are scenarios in which, regardless of the observed outcome, Bob's best guess should always be the same?

Admittedly, this sounds like a weird scenario, but I can't tell whether it can be ruled out altogether (well except in the trivial case in which $\rho_0=\rho_1$). It amounts to asking whether
$$\underbrace{\lambda_0 p_0(0)>\lambda_1 p_1(0)}_{\text{measuring $0$ best guess is $\rho_0$}} \Longrightarrow
\underbrace{\lambda_0 p_0(1) < \lambda_1 p_1(1)}_{\text{measuring $1$ best guess is $\rho_1$}}.$$
Because $p_i(0)+p_i(1)=0$, this is true for $\lambda_0=\lambda_1$, but I'm not sure it holds for the general case.

Comment: Ignoring all the context of the question and purely focusing on the implication with the probabilities, some quick numerics suggests that $\text{LHS}\implies \text{RHS}$ when $\lambda_0 \leq 1/2$. Moreover it would seem that for $\lambda_0 \geq 1/2$ we would have $\text{RHS} \implies \text{LHS}$.

Comment: In fact here's the above comment analytically. If $\lambda p_0 > (1-\lambda) p_1$ then $-\lambda p_0 < -(1-\lambda) p_1$. Adding $\lambda$ to both sides we get $\lambda (1-p_0) < \lambda - (1-\lambda) p_1 \leq (1-\lambda) - (1-\lambda)p_1 = (1-\lambda) (1-p_1)$. Where on the last inequality we used $\lambda \leq 1/2$. The other implication should follow from a similar argument. Here, I've made some shorthand notation: $\lambda = \lambda_0, p_0 = p_0(0), p_1 = p_1(0)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Expression (X) is in principle more general, but it boils down to doing classical post-processing of the outcomes, and this can always be included in the POVM. So as long as you do optimize over the POVM, expression (Y) is completely general.

There are four possibilities:

1. $\lambda_0 p_0(0)>\lambda_1 p_1(0)$ and $\lambda_1 p_1(1)>\lambda_0 p_0(1)$. Boring case, where no post-processing is needed, expressions are equivalent.
2. $\lambda_0 p_0(0)<\lambda_1 p_1(0)$ and $\lambda_1 p_1(1)<\lambda_0 p_0(1)$. In this case you should always guess the opposite of your outcome. Just relabel your POVM elements, $\mu(0)$ becomes $\mu(1)$ and vice-versa.
3. $\lambda_0 p_0(0)>\lambda_1 p_1(0)$ and $\lambda_1 p_1(1)<\lambda_0 p_0(1)$. In this case you should always guess 0, regardless of your outcome, so you assign $\mu(0) = I$ and $\mu(1) = 0$.
4. $\lambda_0 p_0(0)<\lambda_1 p_1(0)$ and $\lambda_1 p_1(1)>\lambda_0 p_0(1)$. In this case you should always guess 1, regardless of your outcome, so you assign $\mu(0) = 0$ and $\mu(1) = I$.

Possibilities 3 and 4 can indeed occur, so the implication you wrote down is false. Take for example $p_0(0) = p_1(1) = 3/4$, $\lambda_0 = 1-10^{-5}$, and $\lambda_1 = 10^{-5}$. In this case you should always guess 1, regardless of your outcome (of course in reality you would just use a better POVM so that your measurement outcomes actually matter).

Comment: but that's the thing, couldn't you still have options 3 or 4 for the optimal POVM? This would be a situation in which even with the optimal measurement your best guess is to always guess $\rho_0$ (or $\rho_1$). In such a case the probability of being correct would be $\lambda_0 p_0(0)+\lambda_0 p_0(1) = \lambda_0$, which might not be equal to $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i(i)$. After all, if $\lambda_0\approx 1$, such strategy would work pretty well

Comment: no, because if this is the case then the optimal POVM will already tell you to always guess 0 (or 1), no relabelling necessary.

Comment: I don't follow. I agree that no relabelling is necessary as you always guess the same, but isn't the expression $\sum_i\lambda_i p_i(i)$ invalid in this case?

Comment: Why should it be invalid? If the POVM tells you to always guess 0 then $\sum_i\lambda_i p_i(i) = \lambda_0$, which is in fact the probability of success.

Comment: because the probability of success is $\lambda_0 p_0(0)+\lambda_1 p_1(1)$ if the best guesses are $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$ when the measurement outcome is $0$ and $1$, respectively. If the best guess is, say, $\rho_0$ regardless of measurement outcome, then wouldn't the success probability read $\lambda_0 p_0(0) + \lambda_0 p_0(1)=\lambda_0$?.

Comment: More specifically, it's not the former expression here because that would be saying "if state is $\rho_0$, which happens with prob $\lambda_0$, we correctly guess $0$ with prob $p_0(0)$, and same with $0\to1$". But that would be saying that when the state is $\rho_1$ we "correctly guess" it is with probability $p_1(1)$; this is not the case: if the state is $\rho_1$, in this scenario, we never guess it correctly, hence $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i(i)$ being incorrect I think

Comment: If the best guess is 0 then $p_0(0) = 1$ and $p_1(1) = 0$, and the success probability is $\lambda_0 p_0(0)+\lambda_1 p_1(1) = \lambda_0$. We do "correctly guess" $\rho_1$ with probability 0.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding with the notation. $p_0(0)$ is the probability of measuring $0$ if the state is $\rho_0$. If the best guess is $\rho_0$ when measuring $0$, that doesn't mean that $p_0(0)=1$

Comment: for a concrete example, consider $\rho_0=|0\rangle\!\langle0|,\rho_1=|+\rangle\!\langle+|, \mu(0)=|0\rangle\!\langle0|,\mu(1)=I-\mu(0)$, and suppose $\lambda_0=1/10$. Then the best guess is always $\rho_1$, independently of measurement results, but $\lambda_0 p_0(0)+\lambda_1 p_1(1)=(1+\lambda_0)/2$ (or $(1-\lambda_0)/2$ relabeling measurements), whereas the true succes probability should be $1-\lambda_0$ (the probability of the state actually being $\rho_1$)

Comment: I know. The point is that you *can* include this classical post-processing in the POVM, in this case by setting $\mu(0) = 0$ and $\mu(1) = I$. This is what makes expression (Y) completely general. Note also that the optimal POVM for this example is completely different.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean exactly by "including this classical post-processing in the POVM" here. I concede that it might be that the optimal POVM never behaves like this, but I don't understand why this follows from what you show in the answer

Comment: Classical post-processing means taking the outcome $b$ given by the POVM and doing something with it to produce your guess. Either doing nothing and just guessing $b$, guessing the opposite of $b$, discarding $b$ and guessing 0, or discarding $b$ and guessing 1. These four are all possible classical post-processings. Whichever you want to do, there is a POVM that already includes it, so you can just directly guess the $b$ produced by this new POVM, making your expression $X$ superfluous.

Comment: oh I think I understand now. You are saying if, given some choice of $\mu$, we get condition (3) or (4), then we can always find a *different* $\mu'$, in these cases a trivial one,  which is equivalent to $\mu$ as far as success probabilities are concerned, and that makes $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i^{(\mu')}(i)$ the correct expression. So then this is always the case, regardless of whether $\mu\sim \mu'$ are optimal

Comment: Yep, that's it. I only mentioned optimality because if you optimize over the POVM conditions (2), (3), and (4) will never arise.